# Nginx. Equal symbol displayed as an error in my editor in Jelastic

Tags: nginx, jelastic

I've this nginx configuration

```
 location /upload/images {
        rewrite "/upload/images/(.*)" /upload/images/index.php?path=$1 last;
    }
```

Seems that my editor in jelastic doesn't recognize the = equal symbol after the path and the editor doesn't format well my code and the code is not readable.
Is there an alternative way to use the equal symbol in the last sentence.

I tryed to put the URL :

```
"/upload/images/index.php?path=$1 last";
```

but nothing changed.

Even this:

```
"\=" or "/="
```

didn't change the way the editor formats the code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot to set the root directory for requests.
Please use following location block:

```
location /upload/images {
            root   /var/www/webroot/ROOT;
            rewrite "/upload/images/(.*)" /upload/images/index.php?path=$1 last;
        }
```